# The CLR cannot set a break point

Tags: clr, breakpoints

Sometimes when I try to set a break point I get an error message saying that the Common Language Runtime could not set the break point.

Even though the code was compiled as a "release" build (I don't want\can't build it again as debug) -

1. I add an ini file directing to the JIT compiler not to optimize it (and also generate tacking info)
2. When I see the loaded module in the modules window I see that it is indeed NOT optimized
3. Under "User Code" (in the modules window) it says N/A. Symbols are loaded and the source code is found automatically.
4. Some breakpoint ARE considered valid and execution does stop there when they're reached

Comment: Maybe you are trying to put a breakpoint at a line without code, or at an instantiation like FileStream fs;

Comment: You'll need to document your question.  CLR version, VS version, a code snippet with the line that fails indicated.